# What is an efficient algorithm to input 4B integers to a text file

Tags: file, io

Let's say I want to write 1,2,3,4....up to 4.096B in a text file. What would be a time efficient way to do it. Just doing it sequentially is taking a long time. So wondering if there's a distributed way.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: If you are going to write it into a single file, then this would be hard to distribute. I suppose you could write multiple files and then copy them together. But it is doubtful if the copying step would not just take the same amount of time as just writing it sequentially.

Comment: Writing numbers in a loop into a file will max out the I/O on your drive instead of being CPU bound. So this will be hard to parallelize (unless you are fine with writing to multiple files on multiple drives).

Comment: I think I have got the idea on how to do it. I am going to generate 4000 files each with a million numbers on a distributed computing framework with each machine working on 2-3 files. Thanks for your response.

Comment: If your I/O operation is I/O and CPU efficient, the copy together step will take the same amount of time as the writing itself, especially if going over network. First, you should make sure you are using efficient output buffering to use the disk I/O to the max. Additionally, the process depends on the source of your numbers. If they are just sequentially calculated by adding 1, there is probably not much to gain. But if they are calculated requiring more processing power, you may gain from filling different output buffers in different threads before writing them to disk with a separate thread

Comment: Hopefully writing all integer values from 0 to some large value isn't the real data you'd be sending, because there's not any real *information* in such a sequence other then "It's a sequence of all integers from 0 to N".  The most *efficient* way to distribute such a sequence would be to write a small program or script that writes the file on the target computer.

Comment: @Thilo *Writing numbers in a loop into a file will max out the I/O on your drive instead of being CPU bound. So this will be hard to parallelize (unless you are fine with writing to multiple files on multiple drives).*  In general, that's true, but to be (overly?) pedantic, complex file systems do exist that can be configured to stripe a single file over multiple devices, for the very purpose of allowing faster parallel access.  IBM's GPFS and Oracle's QFS are two examples.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your comments on my question. It helped me solve this problem in a reasonable amount of time. Here's what I did -

- Create a file using Excel to create a million integers from 0 - 1000000
- Upload this file in Hadoop
- Write a Hive query with 4296 lines like below -

  ```
  a0 = SELECT IPDecimal + (100000 * 1) + 1 AS IPDecimal FROM @file;
  a1 = SELECT IPDecimal + (100000 * 2) + 1 AS IPDecimal FROM @file;
  .
  .
  .
  a4295 = SELECT IPDecimal + (100000 * 4295) + 1 AS IPDecimal FROM @file;
  ```
- Output the result of each SELECT statement above in a separate file and then consolidate the integers in the 4296 files in one single file

Comment: And that last step alone doesn't take significantly more time than just writing all the numbers to one file on one machine in the first place?

Comment: It doesn't at all. Finished in minutes as the data in each file was only in MBs. And the files were on the cluster.

Comment: And writing a local file of that size takes more than "minutes"?

Comment: Local, I didn't spawn 4000 threads/processes to do it since I had a cluster with 100s of machines at my disposal.